# Non-exhaustive patterns in function ev1 (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I don't know why "ev1 global (Let ["z"] (Num 8) (Var "z"))" can not match the evl

It seems that (Let [Nmae] Expr Expr) has already defined!

The answer may be S 8!

```
type Name = String
type Env a = [(Name, a)] 
data Error a = S a | Error String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Expr =  Var Name | Num Int  
             | Expr :+: Expr
             | Expr :*: Expr
             | Let [Name] Expr Expr 
             deriving (Eq, Show)
global = [("x", 1), ("y", 2)] :: [(Name, Int)]
findEnv :: String -> Env Int -> Maybe Int
findEnv v [] = Nothing
findEnv v ((x,y):xs)= if x==v then Just y
                      else findEnv v xs

updEnv :: String -> Int -> Env Int -> Env Int
updEnv v n env = env++[(v,n)]

ev1 :: Env Int -> Expr -> Error Int
ev1 env (Var x) =  case findEnv x env of
                   Just x' -> S x'  
                   Nothing -> Error "not"
ev1 env (Num x) = S(x)

evl env (Let [x] e be) = case evl env e of
                         S v -> evl(updEnv x v env) be
                         Error str -> Error str
```

Comment: `Let [Name] Expr Expr` is weird: why a list of names and not only a single name? In `evl` below you only handle the single-name case. What if the name list is empty or longer than one?

Answer (score 4):

You have two functions: one called `evl` (with an "L") and one called `ev1` (with the number one). Pick one and stick with it.